# Hash sha1 in Python and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, hash, sha1

I have done a script in Python which is:

```
hashed_string = hashlib.sha1(str(string_to_hash).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

and it works as I want, but I can't figure out how to do it in JavaScript.
I have done this in JS:

```
const crypto = require('crypto') 
let shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1') 
let hashed_string = shasum.update(JSON.stringify(string_to_hash).digest('hex'))
```

But the result is not the same.

Comment: Can you pls share an example of the results of each and their differences?

Answer (score 4):

You are calling [hash.digest()](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_digest_encoding) inside [hash.update()](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_update_data_input_encoding), but `digest()` needs to be called after `update()`

e.g.

```
const crypto = require('crypto') 
let shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1')
shasum.update(JSON.stringify(string_to_hash)) 
let hashed_string = shasum.digest('hex'))
```

or

```
const crypto = require('crypto') 
let shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1')
let hashed_string = shasum.update(JSON.stringify(string_to_hash)).digest('hex'))
```

or

```
const crypto = require('crypto') 
let hashed_string = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(JSON.stringify(string_to_hash)).digest('hex'))
```

Provided you are using the exact same string in Python that the `JSON.stringify()` method returns you will get the same result. Any additional characters will affect the result.

For example, here are the generated `SHA1` hashes for some similar strings.

```
#1: {a:1,b:2}          // ca681fb779d3b6f82af9b243c480ce4fb07e7af4
#2: {a:1, b:2}         // 6327727c37c8d1893d9e341453dd1b8c7e72ffe8
#3: {"a":1,"b":2}      // 4acc71e0547112eb432f0a36fb1924c4a738cb49
#4: {"a":1, "b":2}     // 98e0e65ec27728cd01356be19e354d92fb2f4b46
#5: {"a":"1", "b":"2"} // a89dd0ae872ef448a6ddafc23b0752b799fe0de1
```

Javascript:

```
d = {a:1, b:2}  // Simple object
JSON.stringify(d) // {"a":1,"b":2} : #3 Above
```

Python:

```
d = {"a":1, "b":2}
str(d)
"{'a': 1, 'b': 2}"
```

The string created in Python uses single quotes and is formatted with additional space characters so the resulting hash will not be the same.

```
#6: {'a': 1, 'b': 2} // 326a92518b2b2bd864ff2d88eab7c12ca44d3fd3
```

Comment: Thank you for your complex answer. I leaned two new things about hashing from your answer. But I had to send the code to my Laravel backend and hash the code from there. It worked as expected. So I cant say what the problem has been in my case. But thanks again.

Comment: this is not working for me, I have the exact same problem as asked here
```python
msg = "6NmByERB9ZDJX9OKDtIzpGl8ei7KBiYI"+"\n"+"1623776851607"+"\n"+"/api2/v2/users/me"+"\n"+"0" ;
message = msg.encode('utf-8') ;
hash_object = hashlib.sha1(message) ;
sha_1_sign = hash_object.hexdigest() ;
print('sha_1_sign', sha_1_sign) ; # 4ff521a9b87ddd0dea00a842f8f5d72819f9df0a
```
but I cannot get the same hashed in anyway in JS,
your approach gives me 
```js
// c838ca6f79551d828d6e4a810bd49c1df07b54a3
```
any thoughts @Dan ?

Comment: @Jumper Create a new question please and include both the Python and JavaScript code and I'll take a look at it.